# How can I upload my .xsession-errors file to launchpad from the terminal?

Tags: apport

I'm troubleshooting a GUI crash, so I only have TTY access to my system, and I need to upload my .xsession-errors file.
Is there a command to upload a file to an already-existing bug?

Answer (score 0):

In principle, yes, but it may require launchpad authentication which will try to launch a browser (chicken and egg problem).

Try `apport-collect <bug-number>`.

Comment: How does that determine which files to collect?

Comment: Each package can install a file under `/usr/share/apport/package-hooks` which determines the files that are important for debugging issues with that package. apport-collect will run the appropriate script and attach the needed files. However, if the file you want to attach is not identified here, it will not be attached :/ If that's the case, one thing I can suggest is for you to copy the file to a system with a working browser and attach from there.